# Express not recieving POST data

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

EDIT: We are now pretty sure it could be the .htaccess redirecting the POST because in the virtual server in cpanel we can POST correctly using curl, is this a thing. This is our .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.starrynights.co.nz/$1 [R,L]
```

EDIT: I am using express 4.17.1

EDIT: So far with the help of the below I have tried:

- adding bodyparser
- using post man to send through x-www-form-urlencoded
- installing multer and sending through form.data

All have come back with undefined when using postman

---

I am trying to POST to an express server however I cannot get my req.body.message to come back with the data, it only comes back as undefined.

This is deployed on cpanel and is using the Node.js application,
[image]

This is the code installed on it, it works when using localhost, however will not work deployed?

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/", router);

app.listen(3030, () => console.log("Server on 3030"));

router.post("/send_mail", (req, res) => {
    res.send(`the message is ${req.body.message}`);
    }
);
```

**Post Man POST**

[image]

Comment: Can you please add ``app.use(bodyParser());`` right top of your ``app.use('/', router);`` statement? Oh, also don't forget to install body parser middleware ``body-parser`` using ``npm install body-parser`` command. Then require ``body-parser`` on top of your file like ``const bodyParser = require('body-parser');``

Comment: The middleware use in your comment is written as ``app.use(express.bodyParser());``. Can you change it with ``app.use(bodyParser());`` please?

Comment: I am still getting undefined unfortunately, I added in the above

Comment: I am not too sure if the JSON object is not getting passed into the body, or could it be something to do with cpanel and the security side of it?

Comment: Can you send the message with ``x-www-form-urlencoded``? You will need to use ``app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`` middleware.

Comment: Yes, it also could be something related to cpanel. I have still several ideas to test which one is causing the problem. If my last comment doesn't work, please notify me.

Comment: still getting undefined, i currently have these in the code:

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use("/", router);

Comment: Okay, this seems like a problem related to cpanel or some configuration it is using. Let's try something else. Use ``npm install multer`` to install multer package. Then add ``app.use(multer().array());`` before the line ``app.use('/', router);``. Then switch body type to ``form-data`` and fill message field and then send it. Let's check if it can send data using form data. By the way ``app.use(multer().array());`` middle ware is used here to parse form data request body.

Comment: I have added the above, it is still coming back undefined in postman
Edit: I will look and see if cpanel has any specific things that need to be changed, maybe ports etc?

Comment: Yes, that could be the issue. If you find anything, please let me know too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we managed to figure out the problem,
We were using our htaccess to force https but were posting to the http which resulted in the data being redirected.

We changed the POST to only go to the https and it worked perfectly.

EDIT: it broke again, but we found out if hosting using apache and cpanel, it will put a "/" at the end of the POST. So when posting the address must be https://www.example.com/send_mail/ otherwise it wont POST the data

Comment: Good to hear that you have managed to solve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code "as is" and it runs well. Try using following command from windows terminal:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"message\": \"Hello World!\" }" http://localhost:3030/send_mail
```

Comment: Hey Oleg, this runs fine for me when using localhost but I have it deployed on cpanel and when posting to the domain (example.com/send_mail) it comes back with undefined

Comment: I had to remove some of the html to make it fit but this is what is called when i send it too the domain


HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 707
Date: Tue, 18 May 2021 02:22:44 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Location: http://starrynights.co.nz/send_mail/

<title> 301 Moved Permanently
</title></head> 
        <h1 style="margin:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">301</h1>
<h2 style="margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;">Moved Permanently
</h2>
<p>The document has been permanently moved.</p>

Comment: Try to add middleware to the server to see if it gets to it at all or cPanel just redirecting it somewhere else.
`app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log(req.method, req.url); next() })` 
And then look in server logs.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see the console logs, we are not too sure how too get them in cpanel. We are now pretty sure it could be the .htaccess redirecting the POST because in the virtual server in cpanel we can POST correctly using curl above